# Return ArrayList of k-Subsequent of n-Array in recursive function

Tags: java, recursion, combinations

I have the following code that `prints` all `k-subsequent` of array of `size n`

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        int k = 3;
        int start= 0;
        List<int[]> subs = subseq(arr, k, 0, new int[k]);
        
        for(int[] s : subs)
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
    }

    static List<int[]> subseq(int[] arr, int len, int start, int[] result){
        List<int[]> rez = new ArrayList<>();
        if (len == 0){
             /* PRINT HERE WORKS FINE IT PRINT EACH SUBSEQUENT CORRECTLY*/
            //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
            rez.add(result);
            return rez;
        }       
        for (int i = start; i <= arr.length-len; i++){
            result[result.length - len] = arr[i];
            subseq(arr, len-1, i+1, result);
        }
        return rez;
    }       
}
```

My issue is with `rez List` that is `returned` in `recursive` function, It always `empty`, can any one help fixing it ? I tried many solutions none worked

Comment: @JoakimDanielson ok could you fix it ? also the answer given by `Tarun` does no work, I dont know why he `unomment` the line that is inside `if(len == 0)` because I already placed that to show that `print it work there` But I need to print inside `main method` could you please remove his answer cuz I cant

Comment: @JoakimDanielson sorry just becuz I can not remove or vote it I wish if you could remove it

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you were creating new arraylist to store all the sequences .You need to create a single result arraylist which will be storing all the arrays. While adding to  res , i have created new array so that it does not replace the previous arrays that are added. Below is the working solution

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        int k = 3;
        int start= 0;
        Main obj = new Main();
        List<int[]> rez = new ArrayList<>();
        obj.subseq(arr, k, start, new int[k], rez);
       
        for(int[] s : rez)
         System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
    }

    public void subseq(int[] arr, int len, int start, 
int[] result, List<int[]> 
 res){
        if (len == 0){
             /* PRINT HERE WORKS FINE IT PRINT EACH SUBSEQUENT CORRECTLY*/
         // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
          int[] a = new int[result.length];
            for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                a[i] = result[i];
          }
            
            res.add(a);
               
            return;
        }       
        for (int i = start; i <=arr.length-len; i++){
            result[result.length - len] = arr[i];
            subseq(arr, len-1, i+1, result,res);
        }         
    }       
}
```